# R: An interactive graph of a function with sliders in plotly

Tags: r, graph, parameters, slider, r-plotly

To plot a function with its parameters being updated dynamically via sliders is easy in R using basic plot and 'manipulate' package.
Here is an example of a sine wave with its amplitude and frequency being controlled by parameters A and k, respectively.

```
library(manipulate)
manipulate(plot(x, A*sin(k*x)), A = slider(1,3), k = slider(1,10))
```

[image: Interactive graph of sine wate]
However, the basic plot is not as pretty a plotly one. Is there a simple way to do it in plotly?

Plotly provides [examples of sliders](https://plot.ly/r/sliders/) on its site, but the code seems too complex for such a simple task. If plotly does not provide a one or two liner for such tasks, are there other ways to do so in R?

Comment: look at `shiny` package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty shiny app that does it based on one of the examples in the documentation and runs well from RStudio. Lots of opportunity to clean up the code especially in the `renderPlot`, but this will give you a starting point.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

data <-  data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(10,11,12,13))
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sliderInput("sliderA","A", min=1, max=3, step=0.5, value=1),
               sliderInput("sliderK","K", min=1, max=10, step=1, value=1)),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(column(6,plotOutput('waveplot')))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$waveplot <- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(0,10,0.1)
    yfxn <- function(x) { input$sliderA*sin(input$sliderK*x) }
    y <- yfxn(x)
    df <- data.frame(x,y)
    ggplot(df,aes_string(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(size=2)+geom_line()+ 
         scale_x_continuous()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is simpler than what plotly has, though I suspect it can also be simplified. Also, the line data <-  data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(10,11,12,13)) is not needed I suppose.

Comment: yep, very quick and very dirty @irakli. just copied the example code and adapted it for the function in question. about 4 min job that leaves much to be desired.